# Accessing elements from JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list TAGList which have properties like `tagName`, `tagType`

etc..and I am converting this list to JSON string using

```
jsonString = new Gson().toJson(TagsList);
```

and if i print jsonString i am getting the String like

```
[{"Tag_Id":0,"Tag_Name":"cool","Taged_Date":"May 17, 2014 10:39:39 AM"},
 {"Tag_Id":0,"Tag_Name":"cool","Taged_Date":"May 17, 2014 10:39:39 AM"}]
```

I just want display only few properties from this string Like `Tag_Name`, `Taged_Date` and the code looks like this...

```
  type: 'GET',
  url:'xyz.action,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.getJSONObject("Tag_Name"));///throws error telling getJSONObject is not a function
    var JSOb=JSON.stringify(obj);
    var j=jQuery.parseJSON(obj);
    alert(j.Tag_Name); //blank
    alert(JSOb); displays Stringify String..
    alert(JSOb.Tag_Name); //blank
    alert(obj.Tag_Name);  //blank
```

Comment: What type is `jsonString` variable?

Comment: You're parsing it twice. When you set the dataType to JSON it's already parsed, no need to parse it again.

Comment: alert(obj.Tag_Name);  //blank why its not working..??can u tell me plz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array.

The right code:

```
var JSOb=JSON.stringify(obj); 
var j=jQuery.parseJSON(obj);
alert(j[0].Tag_Name); 
alert(j[1].Tag_Name);
alert(obj[0].Tag_Name);
alert(obj[1].Tag_Name);
```

Comment: Oh thanks,alert(j[0].Tag_Name); works fine i am jsu new bee to JSON :)

Answer (score 0):

**Make your post count and More People Will Want to Help You**

If you want more people to answer your questions quicker try putting a little more time into the question.

**Trouble Getting Information from JSon String**

I am trying to access the information from a json I obtained ( by using a better explanation of the following code )
jsonString=new Gson().toJson(TagsList);

and if i print jsonString i am getting the String like

**Here is my JSon Object**

```
[{"Tag_Id":0,
 "Tag_Name":"cool",
 "Taged_Date":"May 17, 2014 10:39:39 AM"},
 {"Tag_Id":0,
 "Tag_Name":"cool",
 "Taged_Date":"May 17, 2014 10:39:39 AM"}]
```

**My Current Request Code Looks Like This**

```
type: 'GET',
url:'xyz.action,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(idx, obj) 
        {
           // the following line throws error telling getJSONObject is not a function
           alert(obj.getJSONObject("Tag_Name"));
```

**Here are some other things I tried.**

```
var JSOb=JSON.stringify(obj);
var j=jQuery.parseJSON(obj);

alert(j.Tag_Name); //blank
alert(JSOb); displays Stringify String..
alert(JSOb.Tag_Name); //blank
alert(obj.Tag_Name);  //blank
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**
I am new to working with JSON and I need some things clarified. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

By the way, feel free to change your question (minus my intent) to this and I will remove my post in favor of the real answer.

Comment: You'll have to learn a little bit about formatting code (4 spaces before each line will do that for you). Also Ctrl+B will bold your sub-titles(I like to add a line return after the sub-titles so they get separated from the following text.)